# Jest - How do I reset object state for each test?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am new to Jest, and I am trying to figure out how to to reset the test object after each test.

**Current Code**

```
describe.only('POST request - missing entry', () => {
    // newBlog is the "test" object
    let newBlog = {
        title: 'Test Title',
        author: 'Foo Bar',
        url: 'www.google.com',
        likes: 100
    }

    test('sets "likes" field to 0 when missing', async () => {
        delete newBlog.likes // propagates to next test
        console.log(newBlog)
    })

    test('returns 400 error when "title" and "url" fields are missing', async () => {
        console.log(newBlog)
    })
})
```

**Objective:** I am writing test using jest to test for bad POST request. i.e. my POST request will intentionally have missing fields for each test.

`likes` field will be omitted from first test while `title, url` field will be missing from second test. Goal is to write `newBlog` object only once rather than rewriting objects for each tests.

**Problem** Main issue here is that the result of first test propagates to next test, i.e. when removing `likes` field for first test, it stays like that and starts the second test without having `likes` field.

I want to know how I can reset the content of object for each test.

**Attempts** So far, I tried few things:

1. I used `BeforeEach` to reset the `newBlog` in following manner:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        let newBlog = {
            title: 'Test Title',
            author: 'Foo Bar',
            url: 'www.google.com',
            likes: 100
        }

        return newBlog
    })
```

However, above code does not work since `newBlog` is in different scope so each test does not recognize `newBlog` variable.

2. I also used `AfterEach` to reset in following manner:

```
  afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
```

This time, it ran but gave me the same results as first code snippet.

I would like to know how to reset objects for each test as many of the solution discussed in stackoverflow seems to focus on resetting *functions* rather than *objects*.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: declare the `newBlog` variable otuside of your `beforeEach`

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this, declare the variable in the describe and reset it in the beforeEach:

```
describe.only('POST request - missing entry', () => {
// newBlog is the "test" object
let newBlog;

beforeEach(() => {
    newBlog = {
         title: 'Test Title',
         author: 'Foo Bar',
         url: 'www.google.com',
         likes: 100
    }

});

test('sets "likes" field to 0 when missing', async () => {
    delete newBlog.likes // propagates to next test
    console.log(newBlog)
})

test('returns 400 error when "title" and "url" fields are missing', async () => {
    console.log(newBlog)
})
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You were correct in needing to use Jest's [beforeEach()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout) function; however, the only things that are returnable from beforeEach() are promises and generators—returning `newBlog` from beforeEach() does nothing. What I would do is create a local variable in the describe function and have beforeEach() reassign that variable before each test runs as seen below.

```
fdescribe('POST request - missing entry', () => {
  let newBlog;

  beforeEach(() => {
    newBlog = {
      title: 'Test Title',
      author: 'Foo Bar',
      url: 'www.google.com',
      likes: 100
    }
  });

  test('sets "likes" field to 0 when missing', async () => { 
    delete newBlog.likes; // remove likes key from copied object
    console.log(newBlog);
  });

  test('returns 400 error when "title" and "url" fields are missing', async () => {
    delete newBlog.title;
    delete newBlog.url;
    console.log(newBlog);
  });
})
```

Additionally, [jest.clearAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) clears all calls and instances of a mocked *function* which will not reset the `newBlog` variable in the way you want to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

I usually deep copy the test object in this kind of scenarios. So I have a helper function (you can use e.g. Lodash's deepClone function too)

```
const deepCopy = (obj: Object) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

In your tests you create a new deep copy of the wanted test object instead of mutating it's state like this:

```
test('sets "likes" field to 0 when missing', async () => {
  let testObj = deepCopy(newBlog)  
  delete testObj.likes // propagates to next test
  console.log(testObj)
})
```