# How to reset state before each test in jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have following classes and files

```
//A.ts 

export abstract class A{
    
    protected abstract method1(arg){
        
    }
}

// C.ts
export interface C{
    public methodC1(){
    };
}

//CImpl.ts
export class CImpl implements C{
    public methodC1(){
        // do something
    };
}

// B.ts
    import appConfig from 'config';
    export class B extends A{
        private _enable : boolean appConfig.get('IsEnabledC');
        private init(argC:C | undefined)
        {
            if(this._enable){
                argC = new CImpl();
            }
            argC.methodC1();
            return argC;
        }
    private func(argC){
        let resource = getResource();
        switch(resource.status){
            case 1:{
                throw(some exception);
            }
            case 2:{
                throw(another exception);
            }
            default:{
                // do something
            }
    }
       
    private cleanup(){
        //do something;
    }
     protected async method1(arg){
            let argC: C | undefined;
            try{
                argC = init(argC);
                await this.func(argC);
            }
            catch(exception){
                this.cleanup();
            }
        }
    }


// B.spec.ts
describe("B test", () => {
    it("check if cleanup is called on resource status 1", () => {
        const varB = new B();
        const spied = jest.spyOn(B.prototype as any,"init").mockReturnValue(new CImpl(argC));
        const spied2 = jest.spyOn(B.prototype as any,"cleanup").mockImplementation(()=>{console.log("cleanup got called")});
        await varB["method1"](arg);
        expect(spied).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(spied2).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("check if cleanup is called on resource status 2", () => {
        const varB = new B();
        const spied = jest.spyOn(B.prototype as any,"init").mockReturnValue(new CImpl(argC));
        const spied2 = jest.spyOn(B.prototype as any,"cleanup").mockImplementation(()=>{console.log("cleanup got called")});
        await varB["method1"](arg);
        expect(spied).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(spied2).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

I want to test two status viz. 1 and 2 for resource inside func method. I have also mocked the getResource() method and setting status 1 and 2 in test respectively. I want that cleanup method gets called only once in each test.
But eventually in second test both spied and spied2 are getting called 2 times.
When I am running each test separately then they are working fine, but when they are run together first test is getting passed and second test is getting failed in expect assertion with message jest.fn() is called 2 times.

How can I reset state after/before each test?

Comment: This might help - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397742/jest-how-do-i-reset-object-state-for-each-test

Answer (score 0):

you can use these methods: `beforeAll, afterAll, beforeEach, afterEach`.
https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown

for clearing mocks you can use `.mockClear()`
https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear

upd:
You can use it only on mocked functions. It can be called anywhere in a test, but you'll probably need it inside afterAll. It will look like this:

```js
import { yourMockedFunction } from '...'

afterAll(() => {
  yourMockedFunction.clearMock();
});

// your tests here
```

Comment: More defined explanation would be appreciated here.